# How to generate a file with env vars in a job in Circleci config.yml

Tags: bash, shell, circleci, circleci-2.0

I'm trying to generate a env.ts file in my Circleci config file with my circleci environment variables. I tried the code below:

```
steps:
  - run:
          name: Setup Environment Variables
          command: 
            echo "export const env = { 
              jwtSecret: ${jwtSecret},
              gqlUrl:  ${gqlUrl}, 
              engineAPIToken:  ${engineAPIToken},
              mongodb:  ${mongodb},
              mandrill:  ${mandrill},
              gcpKeyFilename:  ${gcpKeyFilename},
              demo: ${demo}, 
              nats: ${NATS}, 
              usernats:  ${usernats}, 
              passnats:  ${passnats} };" | base64 --wrap=0 > dist/env.ts
```

but it outputs this:

```
#!/bin/sh -eo pipefail
# Unable to parse YAML
# mapping values are not allowed here
#  in 'string', line 34, column 24:
#                   jwtSecret: ${jwtSecret},
#                            ^
# 
# -------
# Warning: This configuration was auto-generated to show you the message above.
# Don't rerun this job. Rerunning will have no effect.
false
Exited with code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to write a pipe after `command: |`

```
steps:
  - run:
          name: Setup Environment Variables
          command: |
            echo "export const env = { 
              jwtSecret: '${jwtSecret}',
              gqlUrl:  '${gqlUrl}', 
              engineAPIToken:  '${engineAPIToken}',
              mongodb:  '${mongodb}',
              mandrill:  '${mandrill}',
              gcpKeyFilename:  '${gcpKeyFilename}',
              demo: ${demo}, // it's a boolean
              nats: '${NATS}', 
              usernats:  '${usernats}', 
              passnats:  '${passnats}'
            };" > dist/env.ts
```

Note: Also I had forgotten to add '' around my variables.